# MySQL Replace character from column

Tags: mysql

I would like to replace all occurences of `'s` with `s` in myTable's name column.
I tried `REPLACE` but it replaces all records. I want to do it for some customers.

**Note:** Customer is foreign key in myTable.

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

I tried some queries
`REPLACE(name, "'s", "s") from data where cust_id = 1` but this doesn't work

From one of questions I tried `SELECT REPLACE(name, "'s", "s") from data where cust_id = 1`. 
This is replacing all records in table

Comment: Have you tried the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: yes i tried where clause but it is not accepting where clause

Comment: What queries have you tried?  Can you show us the SQL?

Comment: It's remotely possible that you are simply using it wrong. There's just no way that your DBA has *disabled* the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple replace across all records in the table can be done with:

```
 UPDATE myTable
 set    name = REPLACE(name, '\'s', 's')
```

If you want to filter the records to be updated from another table, then you can do something like

```
 UPDATE myTable
 LEFT JOIN CustomerTable ON myTable.Customer = CustomerTable.Customer
 SET    name = REPLACE(name, '\'s', 's')
 WHERE  CustomerTable.Field > SomeCondition <== Replace with what you need.
```

Comment: Thanks man. Why can't I thaught to use replace with update. Anyways, this helped me alot.